# xampp 1.8.2 with typo3 and imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, xampp, typo3

I recently updated xampp to 1.8.2 on OSX and discovered that imagemagick and typo3 do not play well anymore...
In the Install Tool the following error is displayed:

```
Warning: Mismatch between the version of ImageMagick () and the configuration of [GFX][im_version_5] (im6)
```

(ImageMagick is installed via macports in /opt/local/bin Version 6.8.6-6)

The php error logs reports:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/composite
```

When I switch my xampp installation back to xampp 1.7.3 everything works fine. (Identical Typo3 configuration and Imagemagick in /opt/local/bin). 
Imagemagick is found and the install tool shows the rendered images etc. 
I have tried multiple versions of typo3 from 4.7 to 6.0 same error message using xampp 1.8.2 and xampp 1.8.2-beta

In addition I tried to install the imagemagick module via:

```
pecl download imagick
```

but I get the following error:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 250 of 1301 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.
```

Is anyone else having this problem with xampp 1.8.2 and 1.8.2-beta as well - is it possible to get imagemagick to work correctly with XAMPP 1.8.2?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I think the pecl command you tried would just install the php wrapper, not the binaries TYPO3 works with. BTW: Just a personal opinion, but I prefer [brew](http://brew.sh/) and [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I would't use XAMPP on OS X, but rather the built in server, brew or even vagrant.

However, to solve your problem, first install [brew](http://brew.sh/) with the [installation manual](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation).

Then you can just install GraphicsMagick like this:

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

After that, you can reference your new installation in the install tool with the path `/usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `libfreetype` was installed using `macports`, have your tried updating macports?

You can do so from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

When that finishes, execute the following:

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

I have XAMPP 1.8.2 and ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 as well, working nicely on OSX 10.8. What version of OSX are you on?

Comment: I am on OSX 10.8. Whilst installing imagemagick I did port selfupdate and upgrade outdated. I assume the XAMPP 1.8.2 Version uses and older libfreetype Library than XAMPP 1.7.3. which is weird. I tried copying the libfreetype.6.lylib from 1.7.3 and and recreating the symbolic links but that did not work. Nothing would start.

Comment: I was mistaken in the version I use, I do have 10.8. So our systems must be a-like.

Do you have freetype installed from macports? (I have 2.3.12)

Comment: Acccording to port installed I am using freetype @2.5.0_1 (active).